# Definindo value do campo input file

Tags: php

O mundo do projeto é: Faço um cadastro onde eu possibilito o upload de arquivo, ao salvar todo projeto efetuo o cadastro da postagem, e da imagem em 3 tipos de tabelas, a primeira tabela tbl_PUBLICACOES, salvo as publicações, a tabela tbl_IMAGENS, onde salvo as imagens enviadas pelo upload e por ultimo a tabela tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS, onde salvo o código da publicação e o código da imagem. Até aqui esta indo tudo certinho, porem ofereço a opção de alterar esta publicação, e preciso que venha esta imagem referente a publicação ja pre carregada.

> Problemas encontrados:
>   O problema é como irei trocar esta imagem, porque o certo seria deletar ou fazer edição da imagem, para que não encha o servidor de imagem que não está ligada a nenhum arquivo em si. Como fazer da melhor forma, andei pesquisando e ainda não tenho ideia como fazer.

Script que ja programei algo segue abaixo:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS PI INNER JOIN tbl_IMAGENS I ON PI.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM=I.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM WHERE COD_IDENT_PUBLI ='" . $cdPubli . " ' ");

       while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 ?>
        <div class = "fileinput fileinput-new aquiClonar" data-provides = "fileinput">
           <div class = "fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger = "fileinput" style = "width: 420px; height: 190px; text-align: center;"> Tamanho esperado 420px x 190px</div>
               <div>
                  <span class = "btn btn-default btn-file"><span class = "fileinput-new">Selecionar imagem</span><span class = "fileinput-exists">Trocar</span><input type = "file" value="" name = "files[]"></span>
                   <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss = "fileinput">Remover</a><br>
                     <label class = "fileinput-exists">Legenda</label>
                     <input id = "legenda" class = "fileinput-exists" value="<?php echo $linha['MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM'] ?>" name = "MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM" /><br>
                     <label class = "fileinput-exists">Link</label>
                                    <input id = "linkurl" class = "fileinput-exists" value="<?php echo $linha['TXT_LINKX_URLXX'] ?>" name = "TXT_LINKX_URLXX2" />
          </div>
       </div><?php
     }
?>
```

Comment: não é possível atribuir valor ao input file por questões básicas de segurança.

Comment: Como devo fazer para solucionar este meu problema ?

Comment: Pode deixar conseguir encontrar uma saida. irei formular uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

Por questão de segurança não é possível definir um `value=""` para o `input`. A solução encontrada por mim é, fazer uma `query` e trazer todas as imagens referentes a esta publicação e colocar na `tag <img/>` e possibilitar a deleção desta imagem.